Praying on a reflective floor
It's forbidden to pray in front of a mirror, as it can appear like you're praying to your own reflection. What about standing on a mirrored floor (or some other reflective surface), where it can look like you're bowing to your reflection?

Why do you think it would be any different?

@Dov the wording: אסור להתפלל כנגד המראה. Is one כנגד the floor?

@RabbiKaii the issue is the reflective nature of the surface which has two problems 1) Because it is like they are bowing to themselves, 2) and it acts as a distraction thereby lessening the person's kavanna. Both of these issues would be a problem with a reflective floor etc.

@Dov Good points. 1) I have never heard of the concept of bowing to honour that which is on the floor beneath. 2) Only for the brief second when one is at the fullest extent of the bow

@RabbiKaii I would argue with both your points. 1) See SA YD 11:3 we don't shecht an animal over a vessel/bucket with clear water out of worry that it might appear that he is offering a sacrifice to an image reflected by the water 2) A person standing on a reflective surface may well, depending on the light etc. have a larger surface area on the reflective surface that would be seen before the "fullest extent of the bow"
